# Stylus ParseError: expected "indent", got "outdent"

Tags: node.js, stylus

Stylus ParseError: expected "indent", got "outdent"

```
Unable to compile Stylus file app/css/app.styl to CSS: ParseError: app/css/provider.styl:22
   18|  padding-top: 20px
   19|  text-align: center
   20|  border-bottom: 1px solid white
   21|  margin-bottom: 25px
 > 22| 
   23| .aclass
   24|  display: none
   25| 

expected "indent", got "outdent"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any information on this error!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found some hidden white space

:/ watch out!

Comment: also, don't forget you can skip the : if you want.

Comment: what hidden whitespace?  i have the same problem and can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: there were some spaces that weren't visible, not sure how they got in there possibly from copy and pasting code

Comment: When dealing with indent-based languages, it's often beneficial to set your text editor to "show invisibles".

Comment: @JimmyMiller mine was 8 lines up where I had `.d7d7d7` instead of `#d7d7d7`.

Answer (score 17):

I tend to get this when converting CSS files from other libraries. Usually, it has to do with a nearby rule that contains a **filter** property.

When a rule contains any Microsoft "progid" you need to escape the entire value.

```
filter: unqoute("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2b80ff', endColorstr='#1d66d3', GradientType=0)")
-ms-filter: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)")
```

And finally, Stylus has a build-in **alpha** function so you need to escape it with **unquote** it like so:

```
filter: unquote("alpha(opacity=50)")
```

Answer (score 3):

Got same error message when I forgot to quote a path.

error:

```
.bg-img-001
   background-image imgs/img-001.jpg
```

no error:

```
.bg-img-001
   background-image 'imgs/img-001.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue when i've mixed using spaces for indentation and tabs for indentation.

A good way to see if you're doing that is to select the text using Sublime 2-- tabs are bars and spaces are dots in selected text.

In the end i converted the spaces to tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I had a class that started with a number.

```
.1080spacer
  z-index 1
```

etc. The error appeared on the next class declaration line. Once I moved the number to the end of the class, the error went away. Like this:

```
.spacer1080
  z-index 1
```

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was 8 lines up where I had `.e7e7e7` instead of `#e7e7e7`.